# Hibernate Child table updating Parent Object

Tags: java, hibernate

I have table like below,

Role:

```
Role_Id    Role_Name
201        Manager
202        Supervisor
```

User:

```
User_ID   User_Name  Role_Id
1         John       201
2         Peter      202 
3         Raj        202
```

I have created POJO and hibernate mapping file for both tables.

Mapping File:

```
//RoleVO
<class name="RoleVO" table="tbl_Role">
        <id name="roleId" column="role_Id" >
            <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>   
        <property name="roleName" column="Role_Name" />
</class>

//UserVO
<class name="UserVO" table="tbl_User">
        <id name="userId" column="user_Id" >
            <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>   
        <property name="userName" column="User_Name" />
        <many-to-one name="Role" class="RoleVO" column="Role_Id"/>
</class>
```

When I insert user detail in User Table through hibernate, should I get the Role Ref and set it with User object or directly can I add "Role Id" in the User table.

For eg.,

```
//First approach:

UserVO usr = new UserVO();
usr.serUserName("Kumar");
usr.setRoleId(202);
session.save(usr);

or

//Second Approach:

UserVO usr = new UserVO();
usr.serUserName("Kumar");
RoleVO role = session.get(RoleVO.class, 202);
usr.setRole(role);
session.save(usr);
```

Which approach is best? First or Second?

Comment: Could you write the hibernate mapping code, so SO users can give you an adequate answer ?

Comment: The second one, IMHO, the first approach will not work, as you've indicated to hibernate in `many-to-one` association, that you will give `Role` object not a number, remember that hibernate is Oriented Relational Mapping for objects not for fields!

Comment: I would also consider the notion of additional constructors that take arguments so you can construct your `UserVO` by doing something like `new UserVO( "Kumar", session.get( RoleVO.class, 202 ) )`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the User-Role association is Many-to-One and unidirectional association.

Set `RoleVO` object in `UserVO` instance is the only approach to use for inserting `UserVo` object in your database using hibernate as a mapping file indicate:

```
<many-to-one name="Role" class="RoleVO" column="Role_Id"/>
```

So to insert user detail object in your database, you may write:

```
UserVO user = new UserVO();
//Set user info
  ...
RoleVO role = (RoleVO) session.get(RoleVO.class, 202);
user.setRole(role);
session.save(user);
```

I suggest that you check this [hibernate tutorial](http://www.journaldev.com/3793/hibernate-tutorial) for further information.